# Error in DataframeSource(txt) : all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

Tags: r

What could possibly be the cause of this problem?
The library selected are tm, NLP and snowballC.
The error came up when I used this command

```
comments_corpus<-VCorpus(DataframeSource(txt))
```

I'm doing a project on employee satisfaction

Comment: lmk if you need the csv file too!

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to ask a reproducible example

Comment: Yes, please make [mre] :) (Nad you can use `[mre]` to easier ask for this)

Comment: okay got it I'll try asking again

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load the tm package prior to running this code.

library(tm)

Comment: Add block code onto your answer